# C# : Making an exe to not run directly

Tags: c#, exe

I need to make the primary .exe unrunnable from it (When you try to start it directly ,you get a message : Cannot start directly,if it runs from the secondary exe (only it,must have a crc verification i think) then start .

Hope i make myself clear
First .exe can't start directly
Second .exe can start the first exe (only)

Comment: You could encrypt it and only let second.exe have the oey,  but then it is still very easy for a hacker to disassemble second.exe to get the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up the EXE that can't be started directly to accept a parameter, such as a SHA-256 hash of some unique data from the one that's supposed to start it. If that parameter doesn't exist or is not what's expected, display an error and exit.

EDIT:

```
static class Program
{
   static void Main(params string[] args) //<- first needed change
   {
       if(args.Length == 0 || args[0] != "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855")
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Cannot execute this program directly.")
          return;
       }

       ... //rest of main function
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what i need , but how do i do that?:-??

Comment: Keep in mind this is only mildly secure.  It would not be hard to decompile the executable to either find the password or remove the check for it.

Comment: I'll make my own encryption var and pack the main with Themida 2.x , would that do the job?

Comment: Obfuscating the IL would help, but some tools can still read it (obviously the computer can execute it so it's possible to trace through). The trouble is that the code necessary to do this is in the hands of a potential hacker who can take as long as he likes to figure out how to get around it. But, as a simple "don't do it" encouragement to the casual user, it'll be fine.

Comment: @CatalinMihai well, it wouldn't be secure at all, if that's your goal.  It's really not any better than just checking if the arg is "12345" or any other arbitrary string.

Comment: @KeithS Given that this is right at the start of the program and it's fairly simple code (so there really isn't much to obfuscate) means that no matter how much you try try to obfuscate it it won't even be that hard to crack.

Comment: You could pass plaintext into the system and have the program hash it; before comparing the hash to the expected value; that would require the potential attacker to either watch the proper argument being passed in or generate a colliding message. Really, though, Servy's right, it's not a secure way to ensure that *nobody* will be able to start the second executable directly. It's just an "encouragement".

Comment: Thanks KeithS for the example,i'll use my own hashing algorithm and hope that it won't be broken

Comment: Don't use your own hashing algorithm. There are plenty of perfectly good ones out there, and many good cryptographic ones are built in to .NET. It doesn't have to be cryptographic strength, but at least use something like MurmurHash or FNV-1a, proven to have decent avalanche characteristics and at least SOME collision resistance.

Comment: So,which one it will fit better?i don't care about speed,i need protection.

Comment: You've already been warned by two different people that no matter how well you implement this approach, it won't be foolproof, and in fact it'll be far from secure. The most you can do is discourage working around your "security measure" by not making it trivially easy to do so.

Comment: Anyway, if it's protection you want, I'd use SHA-512. There's a built-in implementation in .NET which produces a byte array, and you can convert the bytes to character values to create a hexadecimal string that you can compare with the "target" string. The other thing you can do either as a substitute or in addition, is encrypt and then decrypt the string using an asymmetric encryption like RSA, preventing an attacker from reading the plaintext as it's passed between programs.

Comment: I know this is old, but instead of passing it the SHA hash, why not pass it the location of something and let the second program do the SHA hash. It would be basically impossible to construct an object to make the program get the right SHA hash and then you dont worry about this public/private key stuff and keep all the security. The problem for our theoretical hacker being that he can find the desired hash all day long, but he cant make something that will make that hash. Also, if you want more in depth suggestions on what to do (cryptographically) there is a [Infosec](http://goo.gl/F0LGhK)

Comment: CONT or a [Cryptography](http://goo.gl/YO42FH) website on stack exchange which can help with specifics of the crypto parts

Answer (score 10):

Make the first exe a [DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Then the second program can use it but a user won't be able to run it directly.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do that is to have command line parameters, or beter still, set an environment variable and run it, so theres little way to trace the requirements from a "can I get round the fact you want me to use your app to run it". However, I would say a DLL would be the way to go really.

Comment: @CatalinMihai And why is that?

Comment: because the first .exe its my game,and the second exe my launcher,i need both exe's

Comment: @CatalinMihai That doesn't explain at all why you can't make one a .DLL, or for that matter why it's important that your game can't be called directly either.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the process name (`Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName`) would give you the 1st or the second EXE name but you can  make the 1st EXE as a DLL and the second as an EXE.

Comment: There could be many reasons for this. Remember GTA IV? It had "GTAIV.exe" and "LaunchGTAIV.exe", only through the launcher the "GTAIV.exe" could be executed...

Comment: I can't make DLL,the first .exe its the game itself,and the second the launcher

Comment: another way if the process name wouldnt work would be to rename the 1st EXE filename to any unknown ending, and on runtime from the second EXE you can rechange its Ending to EXE then start it, its not very clean but it would work.