# How can I launch a Windows application ONLY from another application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a WPF C# program launch a second WPF C# program, and prevent this second program from being launched any other way. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe some sort of runtime arguments?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479168/c-sharp-making-an-exe-to-not-run-directly

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the 1st application's Process Id as a parameter, and have the 2nd application look up and validate the calling process.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the second program as a dll, make the entry point internal, and have both applicatios share namespaces. Depending on your level of security, you might want to implement some handshake protocol between both applications.